# An error occurred in my Prisma Client request

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, prisma, database-schema

```
model Post {
  id        String    @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  slug      String    @unique
  title     String
  desc      String
  img       String?
  views     Int       @default(0)
  catSlug   String
  cat       Category  @relation(fields: [catSlug], references: [slug]) 
  userEmail String
  user      User      @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email])
  comments  Comment[]
}
```

Inconsistent query result: Field cat is required to return data, got `null` instead.

and the cat is showing true

My Prisma is giving an error I am new to Prisma and I do not understand where the error is located or what Prisma needs me to do

Comment: What do you mean by `cat is showing true`? Please add entire error message.